# Visual Studio 2017 C++ Mobile Cross Platform: Why doesn't visual studio debug work?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cross-platform

I am trying to understand how to setup cross platform mobile code within Visual Studio using C++ - I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community. Currently using the example C++ cross platform template provided by Visual Studio.

This is for some research and a personal project.

Firstly, I installed the Mobile Development with C++ components with Visual Studio Installer:

[image: Visual Studio Installer Components]

One thing I noticed after installing the components, I couldn't seem to find where the Android NDK component was installed, for my project I downloaded the r15c NDK from [Android Studio's NDK archive](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases) so I could link it in Visual Studio.

After I had installed all of the components, I've restarted my laptop. I've also tried doing a clean install of Visual Studio 2017 Community with the components selected and restarting too (still doesn't work).

I've checked to see if the android settings are pointing to the correct folders in Visual Studio and they are pointing to the right place (at least, from what I understand):

[image: Visual Studio Android Options]

I've tried downloading the Microsoft Cross Platform OpenGLES Application for Android and iOS and running it on my Huawei Honor 9 phone.

Developer Phone Specs:

- Name: Honor 9
- Model: STF-L09
- Android Version: 8.0.0
- Developer Options: Enabled
- USB Debugging: Enabled
- Always prompt when connecting to USB: Enabled
- Selected debug app: OpenGLESApp1.Android.Packaging (I've tried selecting "Nothing" too - doesn't work).

Visual Studio Configuration:

- Solution Configurations: Debug
- Solution Platforms: ARM64 (I've tried changing this to just ARM - doesn't work).
- Debug Target: HUAWEI STF-L09 (arm64v8a - 7BKDU17727003989)
- Target API Level: Lollipop 5.0 - 5.0.2, (android-21) (I've tried changing this to target android-26 to target my phone specific API level - didn't work).
- Platform Toolset: Clang 5.0 (I've changed this to each of the different options available - didn't work).

There are no alterations to the template program provided by Visual Studio.

I expected the application to open up on my phone and run through Visual Studio on debug (hitting any breakpoints I have setup for example). However, the app opens up on my phone and sticks on this screen:

[image: Waiting for Debugger]

Then Visual Studio will show this window:

[image: Command Aborted]

So if I press OK and check the command log, I see this in the output log:

[Command Aborted Output Log](https://pastebin.com/82SeDkh1)

```
=thread-group-added,id="i1"
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.11
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
=tsv-created,name="trace_timestamp",initial="0"\n
0x0000007579636a2c in syscall () from C:\SideProjects\Repositories\CrossPlatformMobile\OpenGLESApp1\OpenGLESApp1\OpenGLESApp1.Android.Packaging\ARM64\Debug\.gdb\libc.so
Loaded 'C:\SideProjects\Repositories\CrossPlatformMobile\OpenGLESApp1\OpenGLESApp1\OpenGLESApp1.Android.Packaging\ARM64\Debug\.gdb\linker64'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libbinder.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libcutils.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libdl.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libhwbinder.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/liblog.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libnativeloader.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libutils.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libwilhelm.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libc++.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded 'C:\SideProjects\Repositories\CrossPlatformMobile\OpenGLESApp1\OpenGLESApp1\OpenGLESApp1.Android.Packaging\ARM64\Debug\.gdb\libc.so'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libm.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libmemtrack.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libandroidfw.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libappfuse.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libbase.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libnativehelper.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libhwlog.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libdebuggerd_client.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libui.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libgui.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libsensor.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libinput.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libcamera_client.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libcamera_metadata.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libskia.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libsqlite.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libEGL.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libGLESv1_CM.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libGLESv2.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libvulkan.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libziparchive.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libETC1.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libhardware.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libhardware_legacy.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libselinux.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libicuuc.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libmedia.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libaudioclient.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libjpeg.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libusbhost.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libharfbuzz_ng.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libz.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libpdfium.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libimg_utils.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libnetd_client.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libradio.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libsoundtrigger.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libminikin.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libprocessgroup.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libnativebridge.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libradio_metadata.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libmemunreachable.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libhidlbase.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libhidltransport.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libhwextdevice.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libvintf.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libnativewindow.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libiawareperf_client.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libc_secshared.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/vendor.huawei.hardware.jpegdec@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libhwui.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libpowerlog.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libservices.huawei.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/lib_oeminfo_interface.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libhuaweicust.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libVulkanContext.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libbacktrace.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libvndksupport.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libaudiomanager.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libstagefright.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libstagefright_foundation.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libstagefright_http_support.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/android.hardware.memtrack@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/android.hardware.graphics.allocator@2.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/android.hardware.configstore@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/android.hardware.configstore-utils.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libsync.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/android.hidl.base@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/android.hidl.token@1.0-utils.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/android.hardware.graphics.bufferqueue@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libtinyxml2.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/vendor.huawei.hardware.hwsched@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/vendor.huawei.hardware.sensors@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libdng_sdk.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libexpat.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libft2.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libicui18n.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libpiex.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libpng.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libmiddlevare_xmlparser.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libGameGraphicsOpt.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libhwgl.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libcrypto.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libpcre2.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libpackagelistparser.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libsonivox.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libaudioutils.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libmedia_helper.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libmediadrm.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libmediametrics.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libhidlmemory.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/android.hidl.memory@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/android.hardware.graphics.common@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/android.hardware.media@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/android.hardware.media.omx@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/vendor.huawei.hardware.iawareperf@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libprotobuf-cpp-full.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libRScpp.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libgpuassistant_client.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/liboeminfo.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libnvme.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libunwind.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libdrmframework.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libmediautils.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libstagefright_omx.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libvorbisidec.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/android.hidl.allocator@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libstagefright_xmlparser@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/vendor.huawei.hardware.graphics.displayeffect@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libstagefright_hwextendedmediadrm.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libpowermanager.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/android.hidl.token@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/android.hardware.sensors@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libstdc++.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libiAwareSdkAdapter.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libspeexresampler.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/android.hardware.drm@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/liblzma.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libxcollie.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libion.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libimonitor.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libhme_jpeg_dec.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libart.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/liblz4.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libsigchain.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-conscrypt.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-okhttp.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-legacy-test.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-bouncycastle.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-ext.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-telephony-common.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-voip-common.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-ims-common.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-apache-xml.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-org.apache.http.legacy.boot.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-android.hidl.base-V1.0-java.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-android.hidl.manager-V1.0-java.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-hwEmui.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-hwTelephony-common.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-hwframework.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-org.simalliance.openmobileapi.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-org.ifaa.android.manager.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-hwaps.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-hwcustEmui.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-hwcustframework.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-hwcustTelephony-common.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/framework/arm64/boot-servicehost.oat'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libandroid.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libaaudio.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libcamera2ndk.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libGLESv3.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libjnigraphics.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libmediandk.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libmidi.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libmtp.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libexif.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libOpenMAXAL.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libOpenSLES.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libRS.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/android.hardware.renderscript@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libwebviewchromium_plat_support.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libjavacore.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libopenjdk.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libssl.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libopenjdkjvm.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libart-compiler.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libart-dexlayout.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libvixl-arm.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libvixl-arm64.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libdrmbitmap.huawei.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libnetutils.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libhwlog_jni.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/vndk-sp/libcutils.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/vndk-sp/libc++.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/vndk-sp/libutils.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/vndk-sp/libbacktrace.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/vndk-sp/libbase.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/vndk-sp/libunwind.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/vndk-sp/liblzma.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libcompiler_rt.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libmedia_jni.huawei.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libsoundpool.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libjavacrypto.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libwebviewchromium_loader.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/libpowergenie_native3.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/vndk-sp/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/vndk-sp/libhidlbase.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/vndk-sp/libhidltransport.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/vndk-sp/libhwbinder.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/vndk-sp/android.hardware.graphics.common@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/vndk-sp/android.hidl.base@1.0.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/vndk-sp/libhardware.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/vendor/lib64/hw/android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0-impl.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/system/lib64/vndk-sp/libion.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.hi3660.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/vendor/lib64/libhiion.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/vendor/lib64/libhilog.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Loaded '/vendor/lib64/libc_secshared.so'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
Debugger was unable to continue the process.
```

I've also noticed that these library ".so" files don't seem to be anywhere on my PC. So I am not sure if I have to download any extra data/software for those libraries. I'd assume, if I didn't have the correct libraries setup, the build wouldn't be successful in Visual Studio and the app wouldn't be able to run on it's own on the phone (which it can do).

Then when I stop debugging the app or tap on "Force Close" on the app on my phone (which is still stuck on "Waiting for Debugger"), this window will appear:

[image: Android Java Vitual Machine Warning]

After that, I can see that the app has actually installed on my phone and can run on it's own if I tap on the icon. The problem appears to be when trying to run in debug in Visual Studio and the debugger can't attach.

To test that my phone debugging settings were okay, I downloaded Android Studio and setup a blank app on that to see if it would run, and it did. So my phone debug settings seem to be correct, it must be something I have to configure within Visual Studio that I am missing out on. I've tried a lot of other solutions I've found online, but most seem to apply to just Xamarin and C# project settings. This is just a native C++ application.

I've spent last weekend looking over the problem and I am looking into it this weekend too, but cannot find a solution to it, I'd really appreciate any help and advice with this problem. Hopefully I've provided enough information, if not, feel free to let me know and I'll get the necessary information. Thank you.

Comment: Further developments: It appears more specific to the model of phone being used. Huawei phones don't seem to work in debug for some reason. Other models of phones work perfectly fine. Waiting for more of an explanation from Visual Studio on this. Still waiting for a solution to this specific issue.